# Need help on regex which allows australian mobile and phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on regex which accepts 10 numbers if it starts with 0 and 11 numbers if it starts with +61 and it should not allow spaces and other symbols.

The below regex that i am trying is working properly for first scenario where it starts with 0 and accepts 10 digits including 0. E.g 0456789654 but the second scenario where i need 11 digits all together ,if it starts with +61 is not working as expected.Issue is its allowing 10 digits also e.g +6134567654 ...But my requirement is it should only accept 11 digits if it starts with +61 for e.g +61234567654.

**My Regex:**

```
^(((([\+]61[1-9]{0,1}|([\(]{0,1}0[\)]{0,1}[1-9]{1}|[\(]{0,1}0[1-9]{2}[\)]{0,1})))([0-9]{8}|([\\s*]|[\-]{1})[0-9]{3}([\\s*]|[\-]{1})[0-9]{3}([\\s*]|[\-]{1})[0-9]{3}|(([\\s*]|[\-]{0,1})[0-9]{4}([\\s*]|[\-]{0,1})[0-9]{4}))))$
```

Please help.

Regards,
Learner

Comment: Sometimes regex is not the option to solve a problem compeltely. You can normally do this with vanilla JS. The regex that you have written is hard to read and understand. Why don't you try vanilla JS here? Though you can solve problem partially and then use logic to do what is required...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it should not allow spaces and other symbols

the regex you're currently using seems to allow spaces. If you truly just want digits without spaces or sybols, something like this should suffice

```js
const rx = /^(\+61|0)\d{9}$/
//          |  |  ||  |   |
//          |  |  ||  |   end
//          |  |  ||  9 digits
//          |  |  |0
//          |  |  or
//          |  +61
//          start

const numbers = [
  "0456789654",
  "04234567654",
  "+6134567654",
  "+61234567654"
]

numbers.forEach(num => console.log(num, rx.test(num) ? "✔" : "❌"))
```